# For each request will the thread ID be different for a asp.net MVC (Orchard CMS) application

Tags: asp.net, iis, thread-safety, iis-7.5, orchardcms-1.8

Considering no explicit thread was created in the codes, for parallel http requests will there be multiple threads serving the requests? Or a single thread may serve multiple requests at a time?

Is it safe to assume the followings:

- Each thread would server only one http request at a time?
- For http requests the dotnet framerowk/IIS would have separate threads serving the request. i.e. one thread one request?

Comment: IIS generally uses a thread for each incoming request.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick, you mean "one thread for one request"? What if there are 50000 requests at a time? Will the requests beyond the thread limit be queued or some threads will server more than on request?

Comment: At some point the server will stop responding once it surpasses it's threshold. It's hard to know what that is because it's very dependent upon the server's setup. Additional options can help though such as creating a web garden where a single application can use multiple processes. For this scenario, you need to use a session method other than in-proc such as a state server and also create a designated machinekey to ensure encryption can be maintained among the multiple processes in the garden.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick, thanks for the info. I think I do not have to worry about that for now as long as a thread serves a single request at a time.